# Why does qDebug modify values if I stream in it a value from a pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I have a problem with qDebug.
When i try to log some value from a pointer it changes the value of my pointers.

I try to be more specific.

This is part of my code:

```
def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->erosion = erosion;
  def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->planarity = CS_nominal/1000;
  def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->tolerance_minor = (CS_nominal/1000) - toll_cs;
  def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->tolerance_major = (CS_nominal/1000) + toll_cs;
  
  qDebug() << "Laser Data " << def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->erosion 
      << " " << def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->planarity 
      << " " << def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->tolerance_minor 
      << " " << def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->tolerance_major;
```

def_pipeline_laser is a "ParameterT" struct from FlatBuffer

```
struct ParametersT : public flatbuffers::NativeTable {
  typedef Parameters TableType;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SmartDevice::Station::PipelineT>> pipelines{};
};
```

erosion and CS_nominal are two simple float which i assign to another flow parameter.

when i do the assignation everything is working fine, as soon as i hit the qdebug the values from my pointer (erosion, planarity, tolerance_minor, tolerance_major) they change to a value close to 0.

if I remove the qdebug or if I use the qdebug in this way everything works fine:

```
qDebug("Erosion = %s", std::to_string(def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->erosion).c_str());
  qDebug("Planarity = %s", std::to_string(def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->planarity).c_str());
  qDebug("Tolerance Min = %s", std::to_string(def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->tolerance_minor).c_str());
  qDebug("Tolerance Maj = %s", std::to_string(def_pipelines_laser->pipelines[0]->param_laser[0]->tolerance_major).c_str());
```

i add also two pictures from the debug to let you understand my problem

[values before qDebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkxyd.png)

[values after qDebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHv1R.png)

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: What about the precision for float numbers? is it really the number shown in the first screenshot? Maybe it has nothing to do with qDebug() but instead with an access of that pointer. Happens the same if the value is stored as double or even long double? or stored as exponentials?

Comment: But they are printed correctly? Is there a problem further in the code? Because in the pictures you are only showing some variables sniffed by the debugger, and they are not required to hold any meaningful values, if e.g. are not used later and compiler decided to optimize them out. C++ programs must follow [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), and hacking your way inside the program with a debugger does not count as observable behavior.